# How many Tomcat instances can one application server handle?

Tags: tomcat

My network engineer states I am part of a cluster where two apache application servers(512G RAM each) have 142 instances each of Tomcat (of which my company represents 6 each with 2G RAM).  This seems like a lot and my latency issues move with the hour of the day - 7AM CST software functions fine, 10AM CST - system slows significantly this slowness continues until 6PM CST.  My question is how many Tomcat instances can one application server handle?

Comment: This is probably a bit "how long is a piece of string", but that does sound like quite a few instances.

Comment: It's a sliding scale, I'd imagine it could handle a few thousand if all they did was print hello world to the screen. The more work each instance does, reduce the amount of instances accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. At one end of the scale I have seen a 1GB RAM, 2-core pizza box server handle several thousand concurrent requests with barely a sign that the CPU is actually doing anything. That was a very well written application. At the other end, I have seen rack after rack of fairly expensive servers (16GB+ RAM, 4+ cores) handling traffic for a site because the app is so badly written if a server has to handle more than 5 concurrent requests the app falls over.

All that said, it certainly sounds like you have a capacity issue.

If it is memory related then the JVMs may start swapping and that will slow them down to a crawl.

My guess is that it is CPU related. It isn't hard for a badly written app to burn through a huge amount of CPU with very few requests.

There is a chance it is network related. With that many instances you might be serving enough content to saturate the network but I'd expect a different failure mode (e.g. dropped connections) rather than general slowness.